# Spring-Boot-Admin is not loading the Admin page & UI is loaded for login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I need help with Spring Boot Admin with version Spring Boot 1.5
Problem: I fallowed the steps provided in github to create Spring Boot Admin App
And I applied the @EnableAdminServer annotation to my Startup class
I can see the login page loading but the styles are not loading and once i hit the login button after entering the username and password it's not redirecting to Spring Boot Admin home page.

Dependencies used are below:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Java Startup file looks like below:

```
@EnableAdminServer
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();
            http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
            http.csrf().disable();

            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.html", "/**/*.css", "/img/**", "/third-party/**")
            .permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

            http.httpBasic();
        }
    }

}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Styles are not loading and the Admin Landing page is not loading(getting 404)

Comment: The order of your operations on `http` matters. It looks like you are authorizing access to css, img etc and then removing it again with the match to `/**`. Try inverting those two statements.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login. Then it will load the correct login.htm with related css files.

Remove this and rebuild and run.

```html
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your `SecurityConfig` like below should work.

```
  @Configuration
  public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login.html", "/**/*.css", "/img/**", "/third-party/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```