# Spring Boot Admin Server redirecting to login.html after successful login

Tags: spring-boot-admin

i have a problem setting up a Spring Boot Admin Server. After setting up a project as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-admin) (note that I am using Spring Boot Version 1.5.19 and Spring Boot Admin Version 1.5.7) I can successfully access `http://localhost:8000/login.html`. The login ui is shown as well. After I type in the username and password the server redirects me to `http://localhost:8000/login.html` instead of directing me to the homepage. Solutions found in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786821/spring-boot-admin-is-not-loading-the-admin-page-ui-is-loaded-for-login-page) do not work for me.

I have setup a GitHub project that reproduces this behaviour. It can be found [following this link](https://github.com/dos7/spring-boot-admin-server).

Comment: Why do you access /login.html? Spring redirects to the page you have requested.

Comment: Even if i try to acces http://localhost:8000/ after the login i can not enter "/".